# Quantum Mechanics Thought Experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, determinism

If a photon approaches a filter with a 0.5 chance of passing through, we have no way of knowing whether it will pass or not. All we know is that if we do the experiment many times, it will pass through 50% of the time.

So, a thought experiment: if we were able to watch a photon pass through the filter, and then if we could rewind time somehow and replay the scene so that all conditions in the universe were identical - does quantum theory have anything to say currently about whether we would see:

`(A) the photon pass through every time the scenario was replayed.`

`(B) the photon pass through 50% of the time, just as if you repeated the experiment in the real world.`

Or is the answer just, "we don't know"?

Comment: We don't know, but I believe most people will say B

Comment: I feel like it would be (A). "Feel" being the correct word :)

Comment: I think, if A were true, then quantum theory would have to have hidden variables. Otherwise, how would the system know what to do?

Comment: @drfk yes, I agree

Comment: I’m also on @drfk’s side

Comment: @drfk can you elaborate on your statement and post it as an answer?

Comment: Voting to close as it is not clear as to what is meant by "rewind time somehow". I get the point you are trying to get at but with some of the things, the devil is in the details. Without even an imaginary operational meaning to the term "rewind time somehow", the question is meaningless and doesn't pertain to any well-defined physical scenario or theory pertaining to the same.

Comment: @DvijD.C. I respectfully disagree. We often consider time reversal symmetry in physics. We can't physically reverse all electric charges in the universe either, or spatially reflect it about a point. Yet CPT symmetry is a core principle. Also see the 1st paragraph of Gilbert's answer.

Comment: @PM2Ring Well, with time-reversal transformation, we have a precise description of what we are doing in terms of the formalism of the theory. I take back my insistence on the operational meaning of what is meant by rewinding time, but it is not clear to me at all as to what is meant even formally by the same (unlike the time-reversal transformation where it is very straightforward to describe what is meant formally).

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks a lot for your comment. I thought a bit more about it and I think this question can be translated to the old question of whether measurements are reversible and hits at the core of differences between many of the interpretations of QM. Put that way, the question can actually be seen as a duplicate of many many questions already asked on the website. However, the way it is framed, it gives one an opportunity to look at the same problem in a new viewpoint (kind of makes it more poignant even if with a quite a bit vague use of "rewinding the time"). Revoking my close vote and +1!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I jump into this question with some trepidation, given that the premise is wildly speculative. But it’s interesting to think about because such an experiment might be able to distinguish between certain classes of quantum mechanics interpretations, which in reality are indistinguishable.

Rephrasing your question: Is the randomness inherent to quantum mechanics fundamental, or simply apparent? Probably most interpretations of QM come down on the side of fundamental randomness. At least one, however, says that QM only *seems* random (due to the complexity of the universe), and there is additional invisible information (“hidden variables”) that would “explain” every quantum event and reveal them to be deterministic if only we had access to it.

Both of the above classes of QM interpretations predict precisely the same results of experiments in our universe because, as far as we know, there’s no way for us to rewind time and repeatedly measure the outcome of *the same* quantum event. The best we can do is attempt to replicate an experiment, but there’s no way to ensure that *everything* is exactly the same.

But suppose we could? Physics would have the tool to resolve one of its greatest interpretational mysteries.

**Edit:** The Transactional Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics (TIQM) is an interesting case. It would appear to occupy a third category, in which despite the lack of hidden variables, quantum randomness is only apparent. From John Cramer’s book on the subject, *The Quantum Handshake* (2016), Section 5.4 “The Mechanism of Transaction Formation”, pp. 66-67,

> Thus, mutual offer/confirmation perturbations of emitter and absorber acting on each other create a frequency-matched pair of dipole resonators as mixed states, and this dynamically unstable system either exponentially avalanches to the formation of a complete transaction, or it disappears when a competing transaction forms. In a universe full of particles, this process does not occur in isolation, and both emitter and absorber are also randomly perturbed by waves from other systems that can randomly drive the exponential instability in either direction. This is the source of randomness in quantum processes.

So if time could be rewound (a particularly apt thought experiment for this interpretation), Cramer would seem to suggest that the same random perturbations would occur (because they are due to the state of reality), thus resulting in the same outcomes. That is, in TIQM, situation (A) is true.

Comment: It'd be interesting to enumerate the answers that the various interpretations give for this scenario. I *think* that [TIQM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_interpretation) would say that A is true.

Comment: @PM2Ring Are you a TI fan? I’ve edited my answer to consider it explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I must admit I *am* one of those rare TI fans. ;) Thanks for adding that info. TI hasn't been developed very much, but I didn't realise that Cramer had published recently about it. Yes, TI is a bit weird, but hey, every interpretation of QM has some weird element. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Nothing to be ashamed of! I’m a TI fan myself. Why do you suppose I have Cramer’s (rather obscure) book at hand? I think it’s genius to treat the time reversed solutions as ontologically real, and as a result, TI intuitively conquers all the standard QM paradoxes!